# Como utlizar um atributo de um objecto para incrementar um contador?

Tags: java

Tenho o exercício praticamente resolvido, falta apenas um "contador".

*"Para a determinação do valor a receber mensalmente por cada funcionário deverão ser contabilizados os clientes por si angariados. Cada cliente deverá ter um atributo com a identificação do funcionário que o angariou."*

Um dos atributos de cada Cliente é o nome do funcionário que o "angariou". Como é que, ao percorrer um array com Clientes, Funcionários e ainda mais alguns tipos de objectos(todos da mesma super classe), posso fazer com que o nº de clientes angariados do Funcionário incremente de acordo com o nº de clientes por ele angariado?

Espero que dê para perceber a dúvida, estou com um bocado de dificuldade a explicar o que quero..

Comment: `falta apenas um "contador".` Eu posso recomendar o que cuida da minha firma, ele é um sujeito muito legal :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na classe do funcionario voce pode ter uma lista de clientes agariados (0 pra N)
Na classe do cliente ter uma referencia de 0 pra 1 com o funcionario que agariou
No método de agariar (na classe funcionário) recebe a classe cliente como referencia e adiciona ela na lista de agariados do funcionario e seta a referencia do funcionario que agariou.

Ou seja em C# ficaria assim, (em Java deve ser bem parecido) :

```
private abstract class Pessoa {
    private string nome_;
}

private class Funcionario : Pessoa {
    private List<Cliente> clientesAgariados_ = new List<Cliente>();

    private void Agariar(Cliente cliente) { 
        cliente.setAgariador(this);
        clientesAgariados.add(cliente);
    }

    public int ClientesAgariados()
    {
        return clientesAgariados.count;
    }
}

private class Cliente : Pessoa {
    private Funcionario agariador_;

    public void setAgariador(Functionario funcionario)
    {
        agariador_ = funcionario;
    }
}
```

No metodo main vc faz o que for necessário e verifica o numero de clientes agariados pela funcao ClientesAgariados:

```
public static Main() {
     Funcionario funcionario = new Funcionario;
     Cliente cliente1 = new Cliente;
     Cliente cliente2 = new Cliente;

     funcionario.Agariar(cliente1);
     funcionario.Agariar(cliente2);

     Console.WriteLine(funcionario.ClientesAgariados().toString());
}
```

Comment: É possível alterar alguma coisa na classe `Cliente` ou `Funcionario` para que não tenha de utilizar o método `Agariar` no main?

Comment: O objetivo de usar a orientação a objeto é ser o mais próximo do mundo real, se por acaso no mundo real da sua empresa um cliente só exista se este ja tiver sido agariado. é possível colocar no construtor do Cliente esta atribuição ex: `public void Cliente(Funcionario fc) { fc.Agariar(this); }` e para isso seria necessário passar o Funcionario no momento da criação do cliente Ex: `new Cliente(funcionario1)`.

Comment: Para efeitos deste exercício, um cliente pode existir sem ter sido angariado por nenhum funcionário. Tentando da maneira do comentário acima, está tudo a funcionar correctamente menos a situação de ninguém ter angariado o cliente. Porque se tentar passar `null` como o funcionário angariador, acontece o NullPointerException.

Comment: Se um cliente pode existir sem ter sido agariado, jamais existirá a situação em que o funcioário deverá ser passado no construtor, pois por definição valores que estano no construtor de uma classe, são indispensáveis para a existencia da mesma, o que acaba nao sendo o caso do Agariador e a primeira solução apresentada fica de acordo com essa realidade.

Comment: Com certeza interpretei mal o enunciado então. Com a primeira solução funciona perfeitamente quer o cliente tenha sido angariado por um funcionário ou não, portanto vou usar essa opção.